# Robovm iOS App verification failed

Tags: ios, app-store, libgdx, robovm

I have created an iOS app with the latest version of `libgdx (java)` and when I upload it to the app store, I receive this error.  I am using correct version of Xcode and iOS 7 SDK.

```
Apple's web service operation was not successful
Unable to authenticate the package: 836379195.itmsp
ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. <br>Do not submit apps built with beta software." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

Comment: Xcode->About Xcode. What is the exact version and build number you are using?

Comment: You have obviously built and submitted your project with a beta version of xcode. Download the latest version of xcode 5 from Dev site and build your project with that and re submit the project again.

Comment: FYI - your app wasn't rejected. I failed verification. Big difference.

Comment: I HAVE CORRECT VERSION OF XCODE. For all who are saying "obviously", you are use a beta version, you would be incorrect.  I have checked numerous times and I iOS 7.0.1 and Xcode 5.0.2, neither of which are beta.

Answer (score 1):

RoboVM uses the Xcode installation pointed to by `xcode-select`. Use

```
xcode-select -p
```

to view the path of the currently used Xcode. Make sure this prints out the path to your Xcode 5 installation and not an old beta Xcode. Use

```
xcode-select -s /path/to/proper/xcode
```

to switch Xcode path. You will have restart Eclipse after you do this in order for RoboVM to pick up the new path.

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
This is the path that I get. I checked the version, and it is 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating libgdx and robovm to their latest nightly builds. I hope this helps people who are have the same issue that I had.